# Вопрос по смыслу

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Есть предложение (один из подпунктов списка):

Разработать унифицированные программы аттестации и испытаний вновь конструируемой арматуры различного назначения, как ориентированные на отраслевые нужды (атомная энергетика, нефтегазовая промышленность, химические производства), так и отвечающие зарубежным стандартам.

Вопросов два. Допустимо ли стилистически писать "как ориентированные на отраслевые нужды... так и отвечающие зарубежным стандартам"? Не будет ли лучше "ориентированные на отраслевые нужды и отвечающие зарубежным стандартам"?

И если оставлять так, то нужна ли запятая перед "как"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фраза  "как ориентированные на отраслевые нужды... так и отвечающие зарубежным стандартам" построена неверно: неудачно использован союз КАК, ТАК И. Его нужно заменить обычным союзом И: ср.: ***"ориентированные на отраслевые нужды... и отвечающие зарубежным стандартам"***.

Причастные обороты  "ориентированные на отраслевые нужды... отвечающие зарубежным стандартам" стоят после определяемого слова, поэтому перед ними ставится запятая.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь не подходит оборот "как... так и" - он указывает на разные программы (и такие, и такие); лучше "не только... но и" (которые не только "отвечали" бы, но и "были ориентированы на [учитывали]"). Если же упрощать фразу, то "отвечающие стандартам" я бы переставил ближе к "унифицированным".

Разработать отвечающие зарубежным стандартам унифицированные программы аттестации и испытаний вновь конструируемой арматуры различного назначения, ориентированные на отраслевые нужды (атомная энергетика, нефтегазовая промышленность, химические производства).